# Effectively using Layout-inflator

Tags: android, android-layout

Let's say I want a custom view with 2 checkboxes. I would start to create a layout file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then create a View that extends FrameLayout, adding the layout using the layout-inflator:

```
mInflate.inflate(R.layout.foo, this, true);
```

My problem with this approach is that I am nesting 2 layouts just to have a very basic view with 2 checkboxes. As I am currently working on a very complex layout, I am seeking for a way to avoid unnecessary nesting of layouts when using the layout inflator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`merge`](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html) tag in your xml layout and then inflate it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

</merge>
```

`FrameLayout` probably isn't the best solution for your layout because it will stack the views one on top of the other.

Answer (score 1):

Create the CheckBoxes dynamically:

```
CheckBox checkBox1 = new CheckBox(this); // or getActivity() depending on code context
CheckBox checkBox2 = new CheckBox(this);
checkBox1.setText("CheckBox");
etc.
frameLayout.addView(child1);
frameLayout.addView(child2);
```